# jQuery AJAX method not working

Tags: php, javascript, html

I'm going to create a page that user can input something in textarea **(index.php)**. When user click on Tweet, it will get all text that user typed to page **tweet.php** (I used jQuery Ajax method). After that, it will redirect to page **show.php**

**Here is my code**

**index.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<title>Tweet</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
      function save_tweet(text_tweet){
      $.ajax
      ({
        type: "POST",
        url: "tweet.php",
        data: "text="+text_tweet,
        success: function(msg)
        {
          if(msg==1){
            window.location.href="show.php";
          }else{
            alert("Error");
          }
        }               
      });
    }

    $("#tweet").bind('click', function(){
      var text_tweet = $("#text_tweet").val();
      if(text_tweet==""){
        $("#show").html("Blank text");
        return;
      }else{
        $("#show").html("");
        save_tweet(text_tweet);
      }
    });
  });
</script>
</head>
<body>
<center>
<textarea name="text_tweet" cols="61" rows="5" id="text_tweet"></textarea>
<br/>
<div id="show"></div>
<br/>
<a href="#" id="tweet">Tweet</a>
</center>
</body>
</html>
```

**tweet.php**

```
<?php
session_start();
if(isset($_POST['text'])){
    $_SESSION['text_tweet'] = $_POST['text'];
}
?>
```

**show.php**

```
<?php
session_start();
echo $_SESSION['text_tweet'];
?>
```

The problem is when i input some text in textarea and click Tweet, it will alert Error. Can anyone know what is the problem?

Thank in advance.

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: Try to `console.log(msg);` in your success function. it's possible that it's simply sending "1" as a string or something alike. On a sidenote though: Ajax is usually used to avoid refreshing or redirecting pages, so it seems counterproductive what you are doing here.

Comment: change `data: "text="+text_tweet,` to `data: {"text":text_tweet},`

Comment: As a matter of fact I think your `msg` will be empty, as you are not returning any value in your tweet.php

Comment: also, in `tweet.php` you not printing anything therefore why `if(msg==1){`?

Comment: It seems you are missing a couple of basic things in your code, I would suggest trying to find a good tutorial with a working example.

Comment: Thank everyone, after i got you comments; now i can solved this problem.

Comment: If the problem has been solved, you can accept an answer to close the question. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Why are you checking if msg is 1 ? Are you returning 1 in your response body ? Looking at the JQuery docs it the success function callback is described as:

```
Type: Function( PlainObject data, String textStatus, jqXHR jqXHR )
```

You could log the value of msg and see what is actually contains.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your code to:

```
$.ajax
      ({
        type: "POST",
        url: "tweet.php",
        data: {text: text_tweet},
        success: function(msg)
        {
          if(msg==1 || msg=="1"){
            window.location.href="show.php";
          }else{
            alert("Error");
          }
        }               
      });
```

**tweet.php**

```
<?php
session_start();
if(isset($_POST['text'])){
    $_SESSION['text_tweet'] = $_POST['text'];
    echo 1;
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
if(msg.length){
            window.location.href="show.php";
          }else{
            alert("Error");
          }
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the dataType in your ajax:

```
dataType: 'text',
```

Add above line in your ajax code.
And change your below line:

```
var text_tweet = $("#text_tweet").val();
```

with the:

```
var text_tweet = $("#text_tweet").text();
```

And in your **tweet.php** file add this line:

```
echo "1";
```